# Add error bars to show standard deviation on a plot in R

Tags: r, plot, statistics, standard-deviation, errorbar

For each `X`-value I calculated the average `Y`-value and the standard deviation (`sd`) of each Y-value

```
x  = 1:5
y  = c(1.1, 1.5, 2.9, 3.8, 5.2)
sd = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4)

plot (x, y)
```

How can I use the standard deviation to add error bars to each datapoint of my plot?

Comment: also see `plotrix::plotCI`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A Problem with csgillespie solution appears, when You have an logarithmic X axis. The you will have a different length of the small bars on the right an the left side (the epsilon follows the x-values).

You should better use the `errbar` function from the `Hmisc` package:

```
d = data.frame(
  x  = c(1:5)
  , y  = c(1.1, 1.5, 2.9, 3.8, 5.2)
  , sd = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.0, 0.4)
)

##install.packages("Hmisc", dependencies=T)
library("Hmisc")

# add error bars (without adjusting yrange)
plot(d$x, d$y, type="n")
with (
  data = d
  , expr = errbar(x, y, y+sd, y-sd, add=T, pch=1, cap=.1)
)

# new plot (adjusts Yrange automatically)
with (
  data = d
  , expr = errbar(x, y, y+sd, y-sd, add=F, pch=1, cap=.015, log="x")
)
```

Answer (score 32):

A solution with `ggplot2` :

```
qplot(x,y)+geom_errorbar(aes(x=x, ymin=y-sd, ymax=y+sd), width=0.25)
```

[image]

Comment: setting geom_errorbar(width = 0) removes caps from both error bar ends. Any idea of how this could be done only on one side of the error bar? Thanks

Answer (score 22):

In addition to @csgillespie's answer, `segments` is also vectorised to help with this sort of thing:

```
plot (x, y, ylim=c(0,6))
segments(x,y-sd,x,y+sd)
epsilon <- 0.02
segments(x-epsilon,y-sd,x+epsilon,y-sd)
segments(x-epsilon,y+sd,x+epsilon,y+sd)
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

You can use `arrows`:

```
arrows(x,y-sd,x,y+sd, code=3, length=0.02, angle = 90)
```

Comment: This answer is better than the answers involving `segments`; simpler, and works even when the x axis is on a log scale (which would cause the solutions using `segments` to draw different lengths to the left versus the right).

Comment: @SmartCH, how do I compute the interquartiles by row of a matrix and then plot the interquartiles and mean as above, please?

Answer (score 20):

You can use `segments` to add the bars in base graphics. Here `epsilon` controls the line across the top and bottom of the line.

```
plot (x, y, ylim=c(0, 6))
epsilon = 0.02
for(i in 1:5) {
    up = y[i] + sd[i]
    low = y[i] - sd[i]
    segments(x[i],low , x[i], up)
    segments(x[i]-epsilon, up , x[i]+epsilon, up)
    segments(x[i]-epsilon, low , x[i]+epsilon, low)
}
```

As @thelatemail points out, I should really have used vectorised function calls:

```
segments(x, y-sd,x, y+sd)
epsilon = 0.02
segments(x-epsilon,y-sd,x+epsilon,y-sd)
segments(x-epsilon,y+sd,x+epsilon,y+sd)
```

[image]