# Omitting axes in plot R

Tags: r, plot

I have used the following code in R to generate this graph:

```
x  <- c(0.916, 0.815, 0.101, -0.029, -0.166, 0.949, 0.073, -0.054, 1.006)
y  <- c(3.91,  5.17,  1.08,   1.28,   1.01,  4.37,  3.97,   0.77,  4.52)
sd <- c(0.35,  2.26,  0.17,   0.08,   0.27,  0.49,  0.65,   0.12,  1.45)
windows()
plot(x,y, ylim=c(0, 8), xlim=c(-0.4, 1.2), pch=19, cex.axis=0.8, 
     cex.lab=0.9, xlab="Male/Female expression ratio (log)", 
     ylab="Z/W expression ratio in females", las=1)
for (i in 1:9) {
  up  <- y[i] + sd[i]
  low <- y[i] - sd[i]
  segments(x[i],      low, x[i],      up)
  segments(x[i]-0.02, up,  x[i]+0.02, up)
  segments(x[i]-0.02, low, x[i]+0.02, low)
}
```

My question is that how I can get rid of the two top and right axes and only keep the bottom and left axes?

[image: in the following picture]

Comment: As a side note, you don't need the `for` loop. `segments` is a vectorised function. You just need to do the 3 lines of: `segments(x,y-sd,x,y+sd);segments(x-epsilon,y+sd,x+epsilon,y+sd);segments(x-epsilon,y-sd,x+epsilon,y-sd);` to get the error bars. This is even said in the answer you got this code from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15063354/496803

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to keep the box-like appearance instead of "free floating" axes, add `bty ="l"` (a lower case L) to your `plot` command.

Resulting in:

```
plot(x, y, ylim=c(0, 8), xlim=c(-0.4, 1.2), pch=19, cex.axis=0.8, 
     cex.lab=0.9, xlab="Male/Female expression ratio (log)", 
     ylab="Z/W expression ratio in females", las=1, bty = "l")
```

This will only remove the upper and the right frame bar.
See also `?par`

Edit:
Looking at your graph and your calculations it seems, that you want to plot means for specific groups and then also show some standard deviation. In this case i would recommend looking into the `boxplot()` command which will do that for you using your original data.
See `?boxplot`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try adding `frame = FALSE` in your plot command:

```
plot(x, y, ylim=c(0, 8), xlim=c(-0.4, 1.2), pch=19, cex.axis=0.8, 
     cex.lab=0.9, xlab="Male/Female expression ratio (log)", 
     ylab="Z/W expression ratio in females", las=1, frame = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

@r0bert & @CarlosV have provided good answers.  There is one other option as well:  You can suppress the axes with the argument `axes=FALSE` and then construct your own using [?axis](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/axis.html), which can give you more control over the [axes](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/axis.html).  Here is some example code (as a bonus, I illustrate @thelatemail's comment about the vectorized version of `segment()`):

```
plot(x, y, axes=FALSE, ylim=c(0, 8), xlim=c(-0.4, 1.2), pch=19, 
     cex.axis=0.8, cex.lab=0.9, xlab="Male/Female expression ratio (log)", 
     ylab="Z/W expression ratio in females")
axis(side=1, cex.axis=0.8, cex.lab=0.9)
axis(side=2, cex.axis=0.8, cex.lab=0.9, las=1)
segments(x,      y-sd, x,      y+sd)
segments(x-0.02, y+sd, x+0.02, y+sd)
segments(x-0.02, y-sd, x+0.02, y-sd)
```

[image]